# PHP - Extract specific html nodes & children and save as json

Tags: php

Total PHP noob, but need to do something down and dirty, and unfortunately... yesterday.

I have a remote webpage I can extract, that has it node structure:

```
--html
  --head
    --body
      --div
        --section id="options"
        --section id="video"
        --nav id="nav"

     // EVERYTHING IN THIS SECTION  
        --section id="inventory"
          --article class="item"
            --div class="info"
              --div class="inner"
                --div class="right"
                  --span class="price-label"
                  --span class="price"
                --div class="left"
                  --a href="http://link-to-details-page.html"
                --div class="center"
                  --h2 class="product-title"
                  --ul class="product-details"
                    --li
                      --span title="title1"
                      --span title="title2"
                        ...............
            --div class="clearfix"
          --article class="item"
            --div class="info"
               ...............
            --div class="clearfix"
            ...............
            ...............   
     // END OF SECTION

        --footer
```

I am a coder, but new to php.

I got this far ....

```
<?php
$url='http://www.example.com/inventory.html';
$homePage=file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($homePage);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body");

// would like to filter this more and parse results to json file



//$file = fopen( 'data.json', 'w' );
//fwrite($file, $homePage);
//fclose($fp);
echo htmlspecialchars($homePage);
?>
```

With my data string already in $homePage, what would be the most efficient way to

1. Capture only the section[id="inventory"]
2. Loop thru its articles collection
3. Remove the div.clearfix node from each article
4. And parse that remaining html string into a JSON object?

Many, many thanks if you can help.

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, if you can show me how to get just the section[id=inventory] and pass it along to a javaScript function, I can handle it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

For anyone else struggling on this ....

**getHtml.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
        <?php
                    $url='http://www.example.com/inventory.html';
                    $content = file_get_contents($url);
                    $first_step = explode( '<section id="Inventory">' , $content );
                    $second_step = explode("</section>" , $first_step[1] );
                    $result = $second_step[0];  
                    $result = trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $result));

                    echo htmlspecialchars($result);             
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div> <!-- response back is posted here success/fail -->
```

---

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(loadContent);

         function loadContent() {
            var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
            var result = (div.textContent);

            // do your code to convert string to json
            // i am leaving that part out in the solution

            phpSave2File(result);
         }


        function phpSave2File(result) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/saveJson.php",
              data: {data: result},
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#result').html(res);
                        console.log(res);
                    },
                error: function(err) {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    }                   
        });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**saveJson.php**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>    
      <div id="saved-results" style="display: block;">
        <?php
            $post_data=$_REQUEST["data"];
            if( $post_data )
                {
                $myfile = fopen("currInventory.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                fwrite($myfile, $post_data);
                fclose($myfile);
                echo $post_data;                        
                } else {
                die('no post data to process');
                }
           ?>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```